# create Views from HashMap inside ArrayList

Tags: java, android, json, for-loop, arraylist

This is a logic problem I can't seem to wrap my head around, but I *think* I'm close. I'm getting values from a `JSON` response and storing them inside a `HashMap` then adding the `HashMap` to an `ArrayList`.

**doInBackground**

```
protected String doInBackground(String... args) {

            // getting JSON string from URL
            companyName = cn.getText().toString();
            projectName = pn.getText().toString();
            String componentName = (String) ab.getSelectedTab().getText();

            List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(3);
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("company", companyName));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("project", projectName));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("component",
                    componentName));

            JSONObject json = jParser.makeHttpRequest(url, "POST",
                    nameValuePairs);

            // Check your log cat for JSON response
            Log.d("All Questions: ", json.toString());

            try {
                // Checking for SUCCESS TAG
                int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

                if (success == 1) {
                    Log.v("RESPONSE", "Success!");
                    // products found: getting Array of Questions
                    questions = json.getJSONArray(TAG_QUESTIONS);

                    // looping through All Questions
                    for (int i = 0; i < questions.length(); i++) {

                        JSONObject c = questions.getJSONObject(i);

                        // Storing each JSON item in variable
                        String name = c.getString(TAG_NAME);
                        String field = c.getString(TAG_FIELD);
                        String value = c.getString(TAG_VALUE);

                        // creating new HashMap
                        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                        // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                        map.put(TAG_NAME, name);
                        map.put(TAG_FIELD, field);
                        map.put(TAG_VALUE, value);
                        for (String key: map.keySet()) {
                            System.out.println("key : " + key);
                            System.out.println("value : " + map.get(key));
                        }
                        infoList.add(map);
                    }

                } else {
                    // no products found
                    Log.v("ERROR", "No JSON for you!");
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }
```

Now the above `for loop` prints the following from my `JSON`

```
06-03 19:35:29.928: I/System.out(9691): key : option_value
06-03 19:35:29.928: I/System.out(9691): value : 
06-03 19:35:29.928: I/System.out(9691): key : field_type
06-03 19:35:29.928: I/System.out(9691): value : Text Field
06-03 19:35:29.928: I/System.out(9691): key : display_name
06-03 19:35:29.928: I/System.out(9691): value : Store #
06-03 19:35:29.928: I/System.out(9691): key : option_value
06-03 19:35:29.928: I/System.out(9691): value : 
06-03 19:35:29.928: I/System.out(9691): key : field_type
06-03 19:35:29.928: I/System.out(9691): value : Text Field
06-03 19:35:29.928: I/System.out(9691): key : display_name
06-03 19:35:29.938: I/System.out(9691): value : Address
06-03 19:35:29.938: I/System.out(9691): key : option_value
06-03 19:35:29.938: I/System.out(9691): value : Education
06-03 19:35:29.938: I/System.out(9691): Health
06-03 19:35:29.938: I/System.out(9691): Computers
06-03 19:35:29.938: I/System.out(9691): Food
06-03 19:35:29.938: I/System.out(9691): Retail
06-03 19:35:29.938: I/System.out(9691): Other
06-03 19:35:29.938: I/System.out(9691): key : field_type
06-03 19:35:29.938: I/System.out(9691): value : Drop Down Menu
06-03 19:35:29.938: I/System.out(9691): key : display_name
06-03 19:35:29.938: I/System.out(9691): value : Type of Business
06-03 19:35:29.938: I/System.out(9691): key : option_value
06-03 19:35:29.938: I/System.out(9691): value : Yes
06-03 19:35:29.938: I/System.out(9691): No
06-03 19:35:29.938: I/System.out(9691): key : field_type
06-03 19:35:29.938: I/System.out(9691): value : Radio
06-03 19:35:29.938: I/System.out(9691): key : display_name
06-03 19:35:29.938: I/System.out(9691): value : Is this business good?
06-03 19:35:29.938: I/System.out(9691): key : option_value
06-03 19:35:29.938: I/System.out(9691): value : Yes
06-03 19:35:29.938: I/System.out(9691): No
06-03 19:35:29.938: I/System.out(9691): key : field_type
06-03 19:35:29.938: I/System.out(9691): value : Check Box
06-03 19:35:29.938: I/System.out(9691): key : display_name
06-03 19:35:29.938: I/System.out(9691): value : Are they nice people?
```

**JSON**

```
{
    "questions": [
        {
            "display_name": "Store #",
            "field_type": "Text Field",
            "option_value": ""
        },
        {
            "display_name": "Address",
            "field_type": "Text Field",
            "option_value": ""
        },
        {
            "display_name": "Type of Business",
            "field_type": "Drop Down Menu",
            "option_value": "Education\r\nHealth\r\nComputers\r\nFood\r\nRetail\r\nOther"
        },
        {
            "display_name": "Is this business good?",
            "field_type": "Radio",
            "option_value": "Yes\r\nNo"
        },
        {
            "display_name": "Are they nice people?",
            "field_type": "Check Box",
            "option_value": "Yes\r\nNo"
        }
    ],
    "success": 1
}
```

Now in `onPostExecute()` I need to loop through my `ArrayList` named "infoList" and then get the `HashMap` values. Based on that info I need to create `Views`. So my code should look something like this, but I cant get it right.

```
protected void onPostExecute(String string) {
    // dismiss the dialog
    pDialog.dismiss();  
    for (int i = 0; i < infoList.size(); i++) {
        // get HashMap, how? i.toString()?
        for (String key: map.keySet()) {
        if (map.get(key).equals("Radio")) {
                //create RadioButtons, setTexts to option_value values         
            } else if (map.get(key).equals("Text Field")) {
                //create EditText
            } else if (map.get(key).equals("Check Box")) {
                //create CheckBox's, setTexts to option_value values
            } else if (map.get(key).equals("Drop Down Menu")) {
                //create Spinner, place option_value values into array and populate
            }
         }
    }
```

So am I making this harder than it needs to be? I feel like their must be an easier way. If not I would greatly appreciate some help writing this `for loop`.

**Edit in response to comments**

I would like this to inflate a layout inside a `fragment` that looks like this

```
Store # ------------------ <EditText>
Address ------------------ <EditText>
Is this business good? --- <RadioButton>
```

etc etc. The `RadioButton` or `Checkbox` will have their text set by the optional_values

When this is done I will send it back to the database I originally got this from.

Comment: Care to show some of your JSON data? It looks like you don't need all of this machinery when some JSON library already has what you need... (personal opinion: `org.json` is a pretty poor library when you want navigation)

Comment: @fge posted the JSON, if there is something to do this for me, please let me know

Comment: Actually yes: what is the output you expect from such JSON input? And what do you expect to do of it afterwards?

Comment: infoList.get(i)   is how to get your maps

Comment: @i_me_mine see partial answer; you should really be using Jackson.

Comment: can you put response string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are making it harder for yourself than what it can be by using an inappropriate library.

Use [Jackson](http://jackson.codehaus.org), you'll have a MUCH easier time doing what you want to do. First, grab your `JsonNode` from your input source, this is typically done via an `ObjectMapper`:

```
// "mapper" is an already initialized ObjectMapper
final JsonNode response = mapper.readTree(yourURL); // catch, treat IOException
```

Now, read `success`:

```
if (response.get("success").intValue() != 1 )
    // deal with failure
```

Success? Deal with all values:

```
for (final JsonNode question: response.get("questions"))
    // do something with "question", which is an element of the "questions" array
```

See the documentation for `JsonNode`. There is simply no better class designed to access/navigate JSON in Java.

After that, if you need/want to, you can use annotations to deserialize each question to a POJO and deal with that. Here is an example I did for a JSON Patch operation:

https://github.com/fge/json-patch/blob/master/src/main/java/com/github/fge/jsonpatch/JsonPatchOperation.java

This file will generate a different implementation of `JsonPatchOperation` according to what the `"op"` member value is; for instance:

```
{ "op": "remove", "path": "/foo" }
```

will generate a `RemoveOperation`.

Jackson may seem quite daunting to begin with; but once you know how to use it, it's a breeze.

Comment: Thank you very very much. This has been a week long exercise in futility trying to manually create a `U.I.` from a `JSON` response. I've used classes, objects, for loops, etc and it's not only slow it makes it very complex. I will look up the API's and get to studying. Hopefully this is the solution I've been looking for

Comment: See my edited answer as well. Jackson is actually EXTREMELY powerful when it comes to deserialization.

Comment: If you need further help, do not hesitate ;)

Comment: one last question actually. I'm already reading up on the API's and the first couple tut's i found from my first Google search. Do you off hand know of any good examples/tuts that show Jackson in action?

Comment: Well, I use it, so yes, I have examples. It depends on what you need. I am mostly a specialist of JSON loading/JsonNode navigation. For starters, see [here](https://github.com/fge/jackson-coreutils/blob/master/src/main/java/com/github/fge/jackson/JsonLoader.java), it is a good example of how to load JSON. See [here](https://github.com/fge/jackson-coreutils/blob/master/src/main/java/com/github/fge/jackson/JacksonUtils.java) for the reader.

Comment: I learn well from examples. Since I'm relatively new to Android it helps me dissect what the code is doing on each line. So for instance an example of once the JSON is received, creating say a radio button from the response. That would be all I would need to see. Then I could go from there

Comment: I have done no android at all :p But I have done Jackson extensively. Note: if you are on Android, go with Jackson 2.2.x, it is "lighter" on Android than previous versions.

Answer (score 2):

Construct a POJO Class for your Questions:

```
Class Questions{
private String Name;
private String field_type;
private ArrayList option_value;
<Getter and Setters>
}
```

Use this as a POJO class. And add this to the ArrayList.

Using a Map is only when you require it. For transfering data using POJO/Business Objects are enough and best suited.

Please let me know your thoughts.

Comment: I am going to try to use Jackson like fge recommended. Thank you for the input, this could work. I just know nothing about `POJO` so I will look into this as well.